# Asp.net memory leak large number of autofac lifetimescope objects in memory

Tags: asp.net, azure, memory, memory-leaks

We are seeing a steady increase of memory usage for our asp.net  mvc application hosted in azure web app. Once memory hits 90% site become unresponsive.

Looking at memory dump we noticed a top large objects are related to autofac.
[image]

Wondering if this is expected or something we're doing completely wrong.

Comment: How did you view the list of objects like that? I downloaded the dmp file from Azure and VS only give debugging options.